# Filter a list using another list using Java8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a List of entities that I would like to filter using another static list. I am struggling with the filter part.

```
 List<Entity> entityList = new ArrayList<Entity>
 Entity e1 = new Entity();
 e1.setId("1");
 entityList.add(e1);
 Entity e2 = new Entity();
 e2.setId("2");
 entityList.add(e2);

  List<String>idList = Arrays.asList("1","3","5","7");
```

I would like to iterate over entityList and get rid of ids that are in the idList. I am doing it as follows

```
  List<updatedList> = entityList.stream()
                                 .filter(entry -> entry.getId().anyMatch(idList))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

entry.getId() is a String, hence I am not able to use anyMatch, as it should be a stream. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need another stream.

First, I'd suggest using a `Set` for the O(1) lookup.

So instead of idList being a list:

```
Set<String> idList = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("1","3","5","7"));
```

Then, when filtering:

```
entityList.stream()
  .filter(entry -> idList.contains(entry.getId()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above should work with `idList` as a `List` (or any other `Collection`) as well, since `contains` is a method on the type of `Collection`.